# How create ProjectExtensions tag with MSBuild for generating .csproj?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

From the MS Developer website:

> Allows MSBuild project files to contain non-MSBuild information.
>   Anything inside of a ProjectExtensions element will be ignored by
>   MSBuild.

See this example :

```
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <UserProperties RESOURCE_FILE="projectName.RC" />
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

I want to create something like above 
for creating .csproj file programmatically, I use

- Namespace:   Microsoft.Build.Construction
- Assembly:  Microsoft.Build   (in Microsoft.Build.dll)

for example :

```
var root = ProjectRootElement.Create();

var group = root.AddPropertyGroup();
group.AddProperty("Configuration", "Debug");
group.AddProperty("Platform", "x64");

// references
AddItems(root, "Reference", "System", "System.Core");

// items to compile
AddItems(root, "Compile", "test.cs");

var target = root.AddTarget("Build");
var task = target.AddTask("Csc");
task.SetParameter("Sources", "@(Compile)");
task.SetParameter("OutputAssembly", "test.dll");

root.Save("test.csproj");
```

I want to know, How can I use these classes and namespace for creating **ProjectExtensions** tag

I saw a method with name CreateProjectExtension() but I dont know how use it.

please guide me How create any **ProjectExtensions** tag